# How to implement #pragma pointers_to_members() for just one class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to use #pragma pointers_to_members() to just one class. 
I have other class definitions in my header file but I want to apply the required pragma to only one class and other classes should not be affected. How can this be achieved? There are not many code examples for that.

Comment: Exactly which compiler is this? I've never heard of this `#pragma`.

Comment: @zwol: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83cch5a6.aspx was the first google hit

Comment: @BenVoigt Eegh. I have a headache now.

Comment: [Use this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck561bfk.aspx) instead.

Comment: @zowl I am using MSVC compiler, working on visual studio 2010.

Comment: @Hans-Passant  I already tried that option. Actually I get a warning C4407 in the Message Map macros in my MFC application. I am using VS 2010. My dialog class is derived from CDialog and a non CObject class virtually. I have followed the standards as recommended by MFC while using Multiple inheritance in MFC. CDialog is the leftmost class in the derivation followed by the other class. But I am unable to weed out that warning. I could do that by putting the #pragma pointers_to_members but my worry is that it should not affect other classes in the header file.

Comment: If you don't show your code then you won't get an answer.

Comment: @Hans-Passant  I solved this using #pragma directive only. Instead of putting it in header file, I put it in .cpp file after all the # include and # pragma

Comment: Nobody still has any idea whatsoever why you needed to solve this "problem" and if you picked the correct solution.  It is doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. I used the # pragma directive just before the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP() in my .cpp file.

```
#pragma pointers_to_members(full_generality,virtual_inheritance)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMy4407Dlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMy4407Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This is my derived class CMy4407Dlg:

```
class CMy4407Dlg : public CDialogEx, public virtual ABCD
{
 // Construction
 public:
CMy4407Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

 // Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_MY4407_DIALOG };

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); // DDX/DDV support
    // Implementation
    protected:
HICON m_hIcon;

// Generated message map functions
virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
};
```